# How to make renderbody content not to appear below the top fixed nav bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my layout code, I'm using Bootstrap v3.0 and Using ASP.NET MVC. The page has to be responsive, I tried using `"space-20"` just below the *render body content*, it works but it doesn't work on small screens. I'm an absolute beginner in ASP.NET MVC

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("Grikwa Store", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand clearfix" })
            <div class="navbar-left">
                @Html.Partial("_SearchPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #68217a;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Account")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: Well... if it's a top fixed nav bar then we assume the content will appear bellow that fixed navbar since it's fixed at the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add some padding to your body-content class.

```
.body-content {
    padding-top: 36px;  /* choose whatever you want here */
}
```

This happens because you have your navbar set to fixed, which is taken out of the normal flow.